# Coloring only Part of a Row in a Table

Tags: tables, formatting, color, tabularx

Let's say you have this table:

[image]

I want to highlight only parts of certain rows. For example, I want to highlight the fourth row, but *only* highlight this row for the first six columns. Then for the last six columns, I want to highlight the last row.

I know you can use `\cellcolor{}`, but it seems rather tedious to do this for every single column. Is there a more elegant way to color only specific cells from a row?

P.S. I know there is extra space toward the end of the table, I have to fix it :)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lccccclccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} &  &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-12}
         & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups & & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
        $\alpha = 1$   & $0.05873092$ & $11/31$ & $1.730157$ & $1$ & $0$ & $\alpha = 1$   & $0.05873092$ & $11/31$ & $1.741681$ & $1$ & $0$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.8$ & $0.0281825$ & $8/31$ & $1.735783$ & $7$ & $1$ & $\alpha = 0.8$  & $0.02822086$ & $11/31$ & $1.732505$ & $108$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.6$ & $0.02425659$ & $8/31$ & $1.711518$ & $26$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.6$ & $0.02380529$ & $11/31$ & $1.727994$ & $226$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.4$ & $0.021494$ & $7/31$ & $1.706627$ & $29$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.4$   & $0.0214516$ & $11/31$ & $1.726991$ & $319$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.2$ & $0.02001998$ & $7/31$ & $1.70708$ & $32$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.2$ & $0.02007049$ & $11/31$ & $1.72622$ & $393$ & $1$ \\
        $\alpha = 0$   & $0.01946719$ & $7/31$ & $1.707758$ & $36$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0$   & $0.01921006$ & $11/31$ & $1.725663$ & $472$ & $1$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** made edits to MWE.

Comment: The MWE cannot produce the image showed. There are several errors, as the lack of booktabs package,  not closing the float options and more. Can you fix this first, please? BTW,  imho the bottom rule is perfect as is, but in `texdoc booktabs` you have how to make rules with another vertical spacing.

Comment: @Fran: I suppose that the statement " extra space toward the end of the table"  does refer to horizontal end of the table (lines continuing to the right margin) instead of the vertical end of the table.

Comment: @Aiden Kenny: In addition to the [previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501787/coloring-only-part-of-a-row-in-a-table#comment1267398_501787), the `landscape` environment is misssing. If I add it, your table is wider than the textwidth. So your MWE must either be missing some font size settings or you changed the margins using for  example `geometry`. Please also add these settings. Could you please also add teh reason why you used math mode for all the numbers?

Comment: @leandriis The bottom line end well in the image. It is not clear what we had to solve in this example,  beside a method to coloring specific a matrix of n × m cells with only one command.

Comment: @Fran: I totally agree with you on the bottomrule looking perfectly fine. My impression was that the OP wanted to refer with their commen to the horizontal lines going all the way to the right margin while the last column ends significantly before the right margin.

Comment: @leandriis @Fran my apologies for all of the errors! 1. Yes, I forgot to include the landscape environment. 2. I changed the margins of the document using the `geometry` package. 3. I suppose there is no reason why I used math mode for all of the numbers. It is a habit that I developed; if the table had negative entries, the negative sign looks weird if it is not in math mode. But since this table has all positive entries, there really is no reason to have it! 4. I was referring to the extra padding toward the right of the table. I will update the MWE.

Comment: @AidenKenny: Thanks for updating the MWE. The `siunitx` package (that I used in the fourth table of my answer)  can also handle negative numbers. Maybe you want to use that. You can of course incorporate that in all of the other layouts as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the `colortbl` package only offers methods to easily color a whole row or a whole column. If you only want to color parts of it, there is the `\cellcolor` command. If you don't want to repeat it with the same color definition over and over again, you could use an abbreviation. (Might also come in handy, if you later on decide that you want to  change the color). Please also note that I have removed the superfluous `$` that surrounded every number in your original example code. Also, I guessed the settings for the `geometry` package as they were not given in your example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mycc}{\cellcolor{lightgray}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering 
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lccccclccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} &  &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-12}
         & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups & & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
        $\alpha = 1$   &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.730157  &  1  &  0  & $\alpha = 1$   &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.741681  &  1  &  0  \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.8$ &  0.0281825  &  8/31  &  1.735783  &  7  &  1  & $\alpha = 0.8$  &  0.02822086  &  11/31  &  1.732505  &  108  &  1  \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.6$ &  0.02425659  &  8/31  &  1.711518  &  26  &  2  & $\alpha = 0.6$ &  0.02380529  &  11/31  &  1.727994  &  226  &  1  \\ 
        \mycc$\alpha = 0.4$ & \mycc 0.021494  & \mycc 7/31  & \mycc 1.706627  & \mycc 29  & \mycc 2  & $\alpha = 0.4$   &  0.0214516  &  11/31  &  1.726991  &  319  &  1  \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.2$ &  0.02001998  &  7/31  &  1.70708  &  32  &  2  & $\alpha = 0.2$ &  0.02007049  &  11/31  &  1.72622  &  393  &  1  \\
        $\alpha = 0$   &  0.01946719  &  7/31  &  1.707758  &  36  &  2  & \mycc$\alpha = 0$   &  \mycc 0.01921006  &  \mycc 11/31  &  \mycc 1.725663  &  \mycc 472  &  \mycc 1  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

You seem to have already noticed that the horizontal lines continue all the way to the right margin even though the table's contents are not that wide. This is due to your usage of `tabularx` that I have not corrected in the above MWE. If you want your table to be as wide as the textwidth and are open to a slight redesign of your table, you might be interested in the following MWE (that also just needs one `\rowcolor` command to color the mentioned cells):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering 
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
                       & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
         $\alpha = 1$    &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.741681  &  1  &  0  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.8$  &  0.02822086  &  11/31  &  1.732505  &  108  &  1  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.6$  &  0.02380529  &  11/31  &  1.727994  &  226  &  1  \\ 
         \rowcolor{lightgray}$\alpha = 0.4$  &  0.0214516   &  11/31  &  1.726991  &  319  &  1  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.2$  &  0.02007049  &  11/31  &  1.72622   &  393  &  1  \\
          $\alpha = 0$    &  0.01921006  &  11/31  &  1.725663  &  472  &  1  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$K$-means Clustering}  \\ \cmidrule(r){2-6}
                       & $\lambda$    & Misclass. & Deviance   & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups \\ \midrule
        $\alpha = 1$   &  0.05873092  &  11/31    &  1.730157  &  1   &  0   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.8$ &  0.0281825   &  8/31     &  1.735783  &  7   &  1   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.6$ &  0.02425659  &  8/31     &  1.711518  &  26  &  2   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.4$ &  0.021494    &  7/31     &  1.706627  &  29  &  2   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.2$ &  0.02001998  &  7/31     &  1.70708   &  32  &  2   \\
        \rowcolor{lightgray} $\alpha = 0$   &  0.01946719  &  7/31     &  1.707758  &  36  &  2   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

---

Starting from this redesign you might also want to rethink if a landscape orientation is really necessary, as your table can fit into the text block of a portrait page (even with standard margins)  perfectly fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering 
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
                       & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
         $\alpha = 1$    &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.741681  &  1  &  0  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.8$  &  0.02822086  &  11/31  &  1.732505  &  108  &  1  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.6$  &  0.02380529  &  11/31  &  1.727994  &  226  &  1  \\ 
         \rowcolor{lightgray}$\alpha = 0.4$  &  0.0214516   &  11/31  &  1.726991  &  319  &  1  \\ 
         $\alpha = 0.2$  &  0.02007049  &  11/31  &  1.72622   &  393  &  1  \\
         $\alpha = 0$    & 0.01921006  &  11/31  &  1.725663  &  472  &  1  \\ \midrule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{ $K$-means Clustering}  \\ \cmidrule(r){2-6}
                       & $\lambda$    & Misclass. & Deviance   & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups \\ \midrule
        $\alpha = 1$   &  0.05873092  &  11/31    &  1.730157  &  1   &  0   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.8$ &  0.0281825   &  8/31     &  1.735783  &  7   &  1   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.6$ &  0.02425659  &  8/31     &  1.711518  &  26  &  2   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.4$ &  0.021494    &  7/31     &  1.706627  &  29  &  2   \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.2$ &  0.02001998  &  7/31     &  1.70708   &  32  &  2   \\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}$\alpha = 0$   &  0.01946719  &  7/31     &  1.707758  &  36  &  2   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

---

Finally, here is the layout I personally would go for. Here I have used the `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal marker and used `>{\(}l<{\)}` in order to automatically set the comments of the first column in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}>{\(}l<{\)}S[table-format=1.8]cS[table-format=1.6]S[table-format=3]c} \toprule

                       & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & {Deviance} & {Sig. Coef.} & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
         \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ 
         \alpha = 1    & 0.05873092 & 11/31 & 1.741681 & 1 & 0 \\ 
         \alpha = 0.8  & 0.02822086 & 11/31 & 1.732505 & 108 & 1 \\ 
         \alpha = 0.6  & 0.02380529 & 11/31 & 1.727994 & 226 & 1 \\ 
         \rowcolor{lightgray}\alpha = 0.4  & 0.0214516  & 11/31 & 1.726991 & 319 & 1 \\ 
         \alpha = 0.2  & 0.02007049 & 11/31 & 1.72622  & 393 & 1 \\
         \alpha = 0    & 0.01921006 & 11/31 & 1.725663 & 472 & 1 \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{$K$-means Clustering}  \\ 
        \alpha = 1   & 0.05873092 & 11/31   & 1.730157 & 1  & 0  \\ 
        \alpha = 0.8 & 0.0281825  & 8/31    & 1.735783 & 7  & 1  \\ 
        \alpha = 0.6 & 0.02425659 & 8/31    & 1.711518 & 26 & 2  \\ 
        \alpha = 0.4 & 0.021494   & 7/31    & 1.706627 & 29 & 2  \\ 
        \alpha = 0.2 & 0.02001998 & 7/31    & 1.70708  & 32 & 2  \\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}\alpha = 0   & 0.01946719 & 7/31    & 1.707758 & 36 & 2  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Choosing a format for a table is always a difficult task. I like having it in landscape since I have other tables that go along with it (not shown in MWE), and in landscape it all fits nicely on one page. I do like the idea of separating the long table into two separate ones! I will experiment with all of your answers and see which one is best :)

Answer (score 4):

To bunch of examples in @leandriis's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501787/coloring-only-part-of-a-row-in-a-table/501802#501802) let me add two more examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mycc}{\cellcolor{lightgray}}
\newcommand{\myccs}[2]{\cellcolor{lightgray}{\tablenum[table-format=#1]{#2}}}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\caption{With use of \texttt{siunitx} and its option \texttt{tablenum} and \texttt{tabularx}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.4pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                            >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l
                            S[table-format=1.8]
                            r
                            S[table-format=1.6]
                            S[table-format=3]
                            >{\centering}X
                            @{\quad}
                            l
                            S[table-format=1.8]
                            r
                            S[table-format=1.6]
                            S[table-format=3]
                            >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]\centering\arraybackslash}X
                            @{}}
                    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} &  
        &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(r){8-12}
$\alpha$    & $\lambda$ & MC & {Deviance} & {SC} & SG   &
$\alpha$    & $\lambda$ & MC & {Deviance} & {SC} & SG   \\
    \midrule
1   &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.730157  &   1 &  0  & 
1   &  0.05873092  &  11/31  &  1.741681  &   1 &  0    \\
0.8 &  0.0281825   &   8/31  &  1.735783  &   7 &  1  & 
0.8 &  0.02822086  &  11/31  &  1.732505  & 108 &  1    \\
0.6 &  0.02425659  &   8/31  &  1.711518  &  26 &  2  & 
0.6 &  0.02380529  &  11/31  &  1.727994  & 226 &  1    \\
\mycc{0.4} 
    & \myccs{1.8}{0.021494}  
        & \mycc{7/31} 
            & \myccs{1.6}{1.706627}  
                & \myccs{3}{29}    
                    & \mycc{2}  &
0.4 &  0.0214516    & 11/31  & 1.726991   & 319 &  1   \\
0.2 &  0.02001998  &  7/31   &  1.70708   &  32 &  2  & 
0.2 &  0.02007049  & 11/31   &  1.72622   & 393 &  1    \\
0   &  0.01946719  &  7/31   &  1.707758  &  36 &  2  & 
\mycc{0}  
    & \myccs{1.8}{0.01921006} 
        & \mycc{11/31}
            & \myccs{1.6}{1.725663}  
                & \myccs{3}{472} 
                    & \mycc{1}  \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{12}{p{\linewidth}}{
    MC: Missclass.,
    SG: Sig. Coef.,
    SG: Sig. Groups}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{With use of \texttt{siunitx} and \texttt{tabular}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.1]
                S[table-format=1.8]
                c
                S[table-format=1.6]
                S[table-format=3]
                c} 
    \toprule
$\alpha$    & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & {Deviance} & {Sig. Coef.} & Sig. Groups\\ 
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Hierarchical Clustering}                          \\
1    & 0.05873092 & 11/31 & 1.741681 & 1   & 0 \\
0.8  & 0.02822086 & 11/31 & 1.732505 & 108 & 1 \\
0.6  & 0.02380529 & 11/31 & 1.727994 & 226 & 1 \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
0.4  & 0.0214516  & 11/31 & 1.726991 & 319 & 1 \\
0.2  & 0.02007049 & 11/31 & 1.72622  & 393 & 1 \\
0    & 0.01921006 & 11/31 & 1.725663 & 472 & 1 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{$K$-means Clustering}   \\
1   & 0.05873092 & 11/31   & 1.730157 & 1  & 0  \\
0.8 & 0.0281825  & 8/31    & 1.735783 & 7  & 1  \\
0.6 & 0.02425659 & 8/31    & 1.711518 & 26 & 2  \\
0.4 & 0.021494   & 7/31    & 1.706627 & 29 & 2  \\
0.2 & 0.02001998 & 7/31    & 1.70708  & 32 & 2  \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
0   & 0.01946719 & 7/31    & 1.707758 & 36 & 2  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` but with further functionalities. In particular, you have a command `\rectanglecolor` to color a rectangular zone of the array. Moreover, you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccccclccccc} 
\CodeBefore  
  \rectanglecolor{lightgray}{6-1}{6-6}
  \rectanglecolor{lightgray}{8-7}{8-12}
\Body
\toprule
         & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} &  &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-12}
         & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups & & $\lambda$ & Misclass. & Deviance & Sig. Coef. & Sig. Groups\\ \midrule
        $\alpha = 1$   & $0.05873092$ & $11/31$ & $1.730157$ & $1$ & $0$ & $\alpha = 1$   & $0.05873092$ & $11/31$ & $1.741681$ & $1$ & $0$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.8$ & $0.0281825$ & $8/31$ & $1.735783$ & $7$ & $1$ & $\alpha = 0.8$  & $0.02822086$ & $11/31$ & $1.732505$ & $108$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.6$ & $0.02425659$ & $8/31$ & $1.711518$ & $26$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.6$ & $0.02380529$ & $11/31$ & $1.727994$ & $226$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.4$ & $0.021494$ & $7/31$ & $1.706627$ & $29$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.4$   & $0.0214516$ & $11/31$ & $1.726991$ & $319$ & $1$ \\ 
        $\alpha = 0.2$ & $0.02001998$ & $7/31$ & $1.70708$ & $32$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0.2$ & $0.02007049$ & $11/31$ & $1.72622$ & $393$ & $1$ \\
        $\alpha = 0$   & $0.01946719$ & $7/31$ & $1.707758$ & $36$ & $2$ & $\alpha = 0$   & $0.01921006$ & $11/31$ & $1.725663$ & $472$ & $1$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]